# How to identify a source button in the bound method?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

In my **xaml** file I bind button command as follows: ... `Command="{Binding MyCommand}" ....`
I use the 'well-known' RelayCommand in my view model to create the bound command as follows:

```
MyCommand = new RelayCommand(param => RunMyCommand())
```

How can I identify the source button in `RunMyCommand()`?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to identify your source button?  Doing so will defeat the purpose of having a bound command in your view model...  If you really really need the source button why don't you just use the Click event?

Comment: Well, I need to keep track which button is currently 'active' because I need to keep one of its properties (e.g. color) bound to a property in my view model.  I can't use focus because the 'active' button might not be in-focus - there are other non-button controls in the view that can get focus while a single button is in 'active' state.  My plan is to keep 'active' button's name in the view model and then use it to change all buttons property (e.g. conditionally if their name matches the one in the view model).  Alex's suggestion will work for me.  Unless there is a better way of doing this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well identify by what exactly? I wouldn't recommend identifying the button itself regardless, so try looking into CommandParameters. Bind or specify something as the CommandParameter and you can receive it into your command.